# Restore a swiped view on pressing back button in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

Hi i was following this tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.l6l53jmw9) about drag and swipe on a RecyclerView using `itemtouchhelper.callback` Everything works fine but what if want to restore the view that was swiped out by pressing the backbutton. how it can be done ?

Comment: post some code of yours

Comment: yaa put your onViewCreated in resume method may be solve it..in MainFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the item which you want restore when you click on the back button. If the object is null, you call the super method else, you add the item in the adapter.

You need to create a simple interface to get the item swiped.

**In the adapter :**

```
private OnSwipeListener onSwipeListener;

@Override
public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
    if (onSwipeListener != null){
      onSwipeListener.onSwipeItem(data.get(position).clone());
    }
    data.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

**In the activity :**

```
T itemSwiped;

// Somewhere after you have created the adapter
adapter.setOnSwipeListener(new OnSwipeListener(){
   @Override
   public void onSwipeItem(T item){
     itemSwiped = item;
   }
});
...
Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (itemSwiped == null){ 
      super.onBackPressed()
    } else {
      adapter.addItem(itemSwiped);
    }
}
```